# How to get error message from a status code or response object

Tags: c#, error-handling, .net-6.0

I have written an api project in .NET 6. I am trying to standardize the response that a client gets when an api is called. I'd like it to be the same regardless of it was a good or bad result.

As such I'm currently trying to standardize responses that are generated by the framework. For example when a 404 or 401 or 403 are returned. Basically handling all the errors from 400 to 600.

I don't want to have to write it out for each status code individually and as such I'm trying to write it in the following way:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode is >= 400 and < 600)
    {
        var response = new CustomResult<object>
        {
            Success = false,
            Errors = new List<CustomError>
            {
                new CustomError("What do I enter here?", context.Response.StatusCode.ToString(), null)
            }
        };
        
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
        await next();
    }
});
```

As you can see, I use an object that I fill out and then I serialize it to json and return to the client. This works as far as I can tell because when I make bad requests I get this json. However, what I can't seem to figure out is how do I get the error message that you would normally get.

Take a look at following example, this is the default error I would get if I turn the above off.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "error": "Not Found",
            "errorCode": "404"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the error says "Not Found". How do I retrieve that from the response object or if not possible, how can I convert my 404 in .net 6 to give me the value of "Not Found". And same for all other error codes of course. I want to get their corresponding error so I can include it in the return.

If you think this is a bad approach, please feel free to let me know and how you think I should approach it.

Comment: YOu can use this enum to get an english version of the status code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
      var st = (System.Net.HttpStatusCode)404;
      var ststr = st.ToString();
```

Gives "NotFound"

Adding spaces to it

```
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var ch in ststr) {
            if (Char.IsUpper(ch) && sb.Length > 0) {
                sb.Append(' ');
            }
            sb.Append(ch);
        }
        ststr = sb.ToString();
```

Gives "Not Found"

If 'context.Response' is `System.Web.HttpResponse` then you can simply use the `ErrorDescription` string in it.

Comment: Right, but that is not user friendly, it doesn't add the space in between words.

Comment: @Bagzli - now with added spaces

Comment: Haha I guess that works, feels like an over kill. Was hoping I can just get the message from the response object the way I get the error code. Would make things simpler. Just wasn't able to figure out how.

Comment: @Bagzli I dont know what `context.Response` is so cant really guess at its contents

Comment: @Bagzli its not clear from your question if that JSON is what you are generating or what you are receiving. If its what you are receiving then where is it in the response.

Comment: that json is what i'm returning to client

Comment: @Bagzli and what is context.Response?

Comment: @Bagzli see edit

Comment: Context = `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext`. Response is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse`. There is no ErrorDescription in HttpResponse object.

Comment: You could use regex to split the error message like this: `String.Join(' ', Regex.Replace(((HttpStatusCode)statusCode).ToString(), @"([A-Z0-9])", @" $1"))`.